# Android: Radio Buttons for Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, radio-button

I am writing an application in which I want to limit access to a menu section from one user group. That user group has no fine motor skills, so I decided that a good way to access the menu would be to use a slider or some other method that requires precision hand movements.

I have been trying to use Radio Buttons to do this; I have 3 radio buttons, and I want to have it so that when they are all checked, they (the radio buttons) become invisible and the button that allows users to navigate to the next menu screen becomes visible.

I have been reading around, but am unsure of how to do this. Any code or tips that point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may have a radio button confused with a check box. http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? You just want 3 Radio Buttons that have to all be selected at the same time in order for a button to appear? Or are you talking about CheckBoxes? This can be done :)

Comment: Yesh, I want it so that when you select all three of the Radio Buttons, they become invisible and an ordinary Button becomes visible. If this should be done with CheckBoxes instead of Radio Buttons, then I apologise for my lack of understanding :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, using the following:

In the XML:

```
   <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onSecondCheckboxClicked"
        android:visibility="gone"        
        android:text="" />
```

In the Java:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v) {
    CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        // Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, "Selected",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void onSecondCheckboxClicked(View v2) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.access_adult_controls);
    if (((CheckBox) v2).isChecked()) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```